# Escape single quotes when passing command to psql -c

Tags: postgresql, psql, bash

I need to run the following command in a BASH shell:

```
sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-15/bin/psql -c "select count(*) from web_site where web_page like '%something%' " -d 'some_database'
```

The output of this command is empty, although if I paste the same query (not enclosed in double quotes) in the psql CLI, it works. So I realised that the issue is in the single quotes, because if I run the following (no single quotes in the statement):

```
sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-15/bin/psql -c "select count(*) from web_site " -d 'some_database'
```

It works flawlessly.

I tried the following:

```
sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-15/bin/psql -c "select count(*) from web_site where web_page like \'%something%\' " -d 'some_database'
sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-15/bin/psql -c 'select count(*) from web_site where web_page like \'%something%\' ' -d 'some_database'
sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-15/bin/psql -c "select count(*) from web_site where web_page like \"%something%\" " -d 'some_database'
sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-15/bin/psql -c 'select count(*) from web_site where web_page like \"%something%\" ' -d 'some_database'
sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-15/bin/psql -c 'select count(*) from web_site where web_page like "%something%" ' -d 'some_database'
```

None of these work. So how do I escape the single quotes?

Comment: Your first attempt works fine for me. What do you get on standard error?

Comment: I get nothing. Neither query output nor any error. Super weird, isn't it?
But if I copy the query enclosed in double quotes into the psql CLI, it executes correctly

Comment: And you get 0 if you enter `echo $?` right after the statement has returned? unusual. Must be some trivial error. Perhaps try as user `postgres` without the `sudo` first as a debugging aid.

Comment: Yes I get 0 if I run `echo $?`. I don't think it has to do with sudo, because similar stuff has been working in the past this way. `sudo -u postgres` is just another way to execute as user postgres.

Comment: I don't think so either, but learn about debugging: you try to eliminate possible causes until you hit upon the true cause of the problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have tried on another machine where it was working previously. Turns out in that machine it works in zsh and not in bash. But in the node where I need to run, it doesn't work in neither bash nor zsh. The only difference is that the node that works with zsh has Postgres 15.2, whereas the node where it doesn't work with any shell (not even sh), has Postgres 15.1 installed.

Comment: Nah. You'll have to debug some more.